# Insert data from Json table to the view that has been already created in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, view, insert

I have a problem, I have to insert data from a Json that stored in a table that has jus one field, just directly insert to the view but as I know there isn't any way to update or insert data into the view, do any one know how can I adjust or set my view to insert data from my table(PS: i can't use insert into or select into)

my first table that has Json data:

```
|  JsonOutPut                                                                   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|[{"FID":1,"Fname":"cake","Fcount":5,"FDate":"2020-02-13","Fregion":"UK"},...]  |
```

my view should be like this:

```
| FID | Fname | Fcount| FDate    | Fregion |
|-----|-------|-------|----------|---------|
|  1  | cake  |   5   |2020-02-13|    UK   |
```

I don't want create new table!

Comment: A **view** in SQL Server doesn't store any data - it just displays data from tables. So you **cannot** insert data into a view - you insert it into the *underlying table(s)* and the view will display it....

Comment: I know i want to show my table  from Json directly to the view with proper format!

Answer (score 2):

```
create table jtable(JsonOutPut nvarchar(max));
go
insert into jtable(JsonOutPut)
values('[{"FID":1,"Fname":"cake","Fcount":5,"FDate":"2020-02-13","Fregion":"UK"},{"FID":2,"Fname":"pie","Fcount":15,"FDate":"2020-02-15","Fregion":"UK"}]'),
('[{"FID":100,"Fname":"cake100","Fcount":1005,"FDate":"2020-02-13","Fregion":"UK100"},{"FID":1002,"Fname":"pie100","Fcount":10015,"FDate":"2020-02-15","Fregion":"UK100"}]');
go

create view jview
as
select oj.FID, oj.Fname, oj.Fcount, oj.FDate, oj.Fregion
from jtable
cross apply openjson(JsonOutPut) 
with
(
FID int '$.FID',
Fname varchar(100) '$.Fname',
Fcount int '$.Fcount',
FDate date '$.FDate',
Fregion varchar(20) '$.Fregion'
) as oj
go

select *
from jview
go

drop view if exists jview
drop table if exists jtable
go
```

Comment: this won't help me, i don't want to create a new table! btw tnx

Comment: @SaraMoradi You don't have to create a new table, the create table portion of this answer is only to provide a complete working example. You can just use the `create view` portion for your purposes. See [this DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ac7ca817c4b24f35946c3d829194178) for more info. The first statement merely sets up the table for the view, the second statement is the view you need to create, and the 3rd is just showing that the view works as you asked.

Comment: As I said, I wanna create a view then insert data from this Json table to that view!

Comment: @SaraMoradi . . . Inserting data into a view doesn't really make sense -- I mean, if you have an updatable view, you can just use `insert`.  In any case, this answers the hard part of your question which is parsing data.

Comment: actually i wrote a proc better and more efficent than yours, but as i said i want to insert my data into the view

Answer (score -1):

I wrote the query but it has a error:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[viewJson]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @OpenJson NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT * FROM FoodSara_tbl FOR JSON AUTO)

SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@OpenJson)

WITH (FID INT,
Fname NVARCHAR(50),
Ftype NVARCHAR(20),
Fcount INT,
Fdate VARCHAR(400),
Fregion NVARCHAR(50),
Fdescription NVARCHAR(100)) AS SM


EXEC('CREATE VIEW Json1 AS SELECT * FROM SM')

END
```